# Enterprise Architect version 7.5.844 State Diagrams

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

i am trying to learn EA but got stuck trying to produce State Diagrams.

when i start a new project it gives me several option regarding what kind of document i wish to create. but i dont see the option to creat state diagrams.

am i overlooking something?

apologies for not being a programming question.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create any diagram... Click on the "More Tools" button bellow toolbox title on the left screen and then choose "State" toolbox.

Comment: Thats what im doing but what "model" should be for state diagrams? thanks.

Comment: I believe that a state diagram addresses the dynamic view and therefore you can put it in the "Dynamic View Model". But, it also can be used to represent the dynamic aspects in the "Logical View Model".

Answer (score 3):

In Enterprise Architect 8:

- create a new Project from the File Menu,
- cancel the dialog "Select Model(s)".
- add a package to the Model by select "Add Package..." from the Project menu.
- In the following dialog select "Class view" give it a name and click "ok".
- After that select "Add Diagram..." from the Project menu.
- In the list "Select Form" on the left side select "UML Behavioral",
- in the list "Diagram Types" select "State Machine".

That's it!